# Gremlin calculate date difference from today

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

Date was stored in gremlin. I want to get months between stored date and today.

Is it possible to write only using gremlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do date calculations without using a lambda at this time:

```
gremlin> import java.time.*
...
gremlin> import java.time.temporal.*
...
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('event').property('d', new LocalDate(2020,8,1))
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().values('d').map{ Period.between(it.get(), LocalDate.now()).getMonths() }
==>4
```

If you stored your date as a long, I suppose that you could get the time difference without a lambda, but then you'd need to somehow calculate "months" from that.